# If in object pushing

Tags: javascript

I want to create object that will contain x-amount datasets only if the data for each of the datasets.data (londonTemp, nyTemp) is higher than 0. My attempt would be to put `if` in front of the second dataset object, but cannot do it.

```
var container = {
    temp : {
        labels: "",
        datasets: [
            { 
              label: "London", 
              type: "bar",
              data: londonTemp
            },
            {                          // this object
              label: "NY",             // to exist
              type: "line",            // only if
              data: nyTemp             // nyTemp > 0
            }
       ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would filter by data > 0

```
var container = {
    temp : {
        labels: "",
        datasets: [
            { 
              label: "London", 
              type: "bar",
              data: 5
            },
            {                          // this object
              label: "NY",             // to exist
              type: "line",            // only if
              data: 0             // nyTemp > 0
            }
       ]
    }
};

container.temp.datasets = container.temp.datasets.filter(function(one){return one.data > 0});
```

Answer (score 6):

Push this object in separate `if` block:

```
var container = {
  temp: {
    labels: "",
    datasets: [{
      label: "London",
      type: "bar",
      data: londonTemp
    }]
  }
};

if (nyTemp > 0) {
  container.temp.datasets.push({
    label: "NY",
    type: "line",
    data: nyTemp
  })
}
```

Comment: @lovemyjob we all sometime don't see obvious, it's fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to filter all items whose data is greater than `0`.

```
container.temp.dataset.filter(item => item.data > 0);
```

I personally think that using `filter` is cleaner and more robust than using `if` + `push`.